# android import ressources from library project

Tags: android, xml, resources, android-library

is it possible to use ressources like strings that are defined in library projects in the application-projects? if so, how?
because i cant seem to resolve the strings i would like to resolve like this:

```
String title = "sample";
int id = ressources.getIdentifier(title, "string", "com.package");
```

gives me this exception

WARN/ResourceType(278): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
WARN/System.err(278): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

the string ("sample") i am looking for is definitely in this package provided in the strings.xml of the library project. i can even see it in the R.java

Comment: is com.package the package defined in your library projects AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: yes it is. all classes are in this package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it looks like

> int id = ressources.getIdentifier(title, "string", "com.package");

is returning `0`, meaning it can't find the specified resource. The subsequent call to `ressources.getIdentifer()` causes the exception, since `0` is not a valid resource id.

Here are some debug/alternative ideas:

---

- You've probably already done this a dozen times, but it doesn't hurt mentioning: first recheck spelling of everything:

  - package spelling is correct (both in library project and in client project),
  - resource string is correct (library project and client project),
  - is library spelling correct in the `uses-library` element the `AndroidManifest.xml`,
  - etc.

---

- Can you access any resources in that library or is the problem specific to that resource (`title`) or is it specific to that type of resource(strings)? Can you access the resources of another library?

---

- Are you accessing the library as a jar file?  You can jar the code, but you can't access resources from a jar.

[Android - Is it possible to create a custom library to use across several applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828448/android-is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-library-to-use-across-several-appilca/1830774#1830774)

---

- Did you try the alternate name format:

Code

```
String fullyQualifiedResourceName = "com.package:string/sample";
int id = ressources.getIdentifier(title, null, null);
if (id == 0) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Lookup id for resource '"+fullyQualifiedResourceName+"' failed";
    // graceful error handling code here
}
```

---

- You could try using reflection:

Code

```
final String resourceName= "sample";
final int id;
try {
    final Class resourceType = com.package.R.string.class;
    final Field field = resourceType.getField(title);
    id = field.getInt(null);
} catch (final Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Lookup id for resource '"+resourceName+"' failed";
    // graceful error handling code here
}
```

[Android, getting resource ID from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string/4428288#4428288)

http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! the library i am using is not a jar, it is merely another project in eclipse which i have referenced using the android project properties. using the version with the fullyQualifiedResourceName gives the same error.

Comment: the version with reflection did infact work but i still would like to understand why the 'official' one didnt.

Comment: @clamp - I tried tracing through the source for clues, but the code goes into native code pretty quick and I have more trouble following beyond there.  http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java;hb=HEAD  ; http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java ; http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp

Answer (score 3):

In your project code, import the R class:

`import com.application.libraryproject.R`

Then you can reference any string or other xml-defined resource like this:

`String mystring = getString(R.string.app_name);`

or similar.

Comment: thanks, actually my question was wrong. my problem is infact to get the id of the ressource, which i try to find using getIdentifier and it's name.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and I solved it with the `getPackageName()` method within the Project Library.

In your case, it should be:

```
String title = "sample";
int id = ressources.getIdentifier(title, "string", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, define the resources in your library project like normal.  Then reference them in the project importing the library by prepending the R class with the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml of the library.

Comment: ok, but what if i want to get the string with this function getResources().getString( int id )

Comment: Its exactly the same as using the standard R class, getResources().getSTring(R.string.somestringyouwanttouse)

Comment: thanks, actually my previous comment was wrong. i am trying to find the id by its name. i have now corrected my original post.