# Web Page in res/raw/

Tags: android, html

I want to use a webpage to display my content because that will utilize the built in zoom and scroll feature in android. I know that I want to have the webpage on the sdcard to allow for not having internet access, but I don't know how to call it from the res/raw/ folder. Can I get some help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the webpage in the `assets` folder instead. Then when you want to load it, use this line of code:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myWebPage.html");
```

Answer (score 7):

There is one condition that we cannot use `assets` folder. What if we want to have a WebView load resource from library project. `assets` folder is not supported but `res/raw` does.

As long as I know, the following work fine starting from API 8:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/webPage.html");
```

Comment: Why minus me? I am telling the fact!! Reference asset in library project is possible but it need [special handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346889/how-to-reference-an-asset-in-a-library-project) !!!!

Comment: Thanks, for me this worked. using res/raw/ and res/raw-us/ only this worked! thanks!

Comment: Be aware that a workaround is needed when the _aplication id_ is different in a _buildVariant_, like for example [with a suffix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777566/file-under-res-raw-not-accessible-in-debug-buildvariant).

Answer (score 0):

First get String from Drawable Folder, see following link to get contetnts of a file from raw folder:

http://www.41post.com/3985/programming/android-loading-files-from-the-assets-and-raw-folders

and Then you can use WebView's loadData method to load html contents in webview.

Other method is to load html file by:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an html file from the assets folder like this

```
WebView wv;  
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html");
```

Comment: Would I need to make a WebView in the main.xml for this method? I ask that because of the use of findViewById

Comment: You can put the web view either in the main.xml file or just include to the layout programatically using java.