# File under /res/raw not accessible in Debug buildvariant

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

In an Android Studio / Gradle Android project, I have two build variants, Debug And Release (the standard project setup).

You can see my folder structure in this picture:

[image]

I have a WebView that should display the imprint.html from the /res/raw-folder. 
This works in teh release build, but not the debug build, the WebView says

```
Couldn't load website under 'file///android_res/raw/imprint.hml
net::EE_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

which puzzles me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting your html inside assets. Like `file:///android_asset/imprint.html`

Comment: Did you have resolve this ?

Comment: @Xero Sorry I don't know, haven't tried in a long time. But I can't recall any particular solution.

Comment: @Xero Did anyone find a solution to this? Using the asset folder is not a good solution, as it doesn't natively allow for internationalization.

Comment: Can you show the code that tries to reference this file and generates the error as you show it? Without code, you may only get speculation.

Comment: Can you please update here with your gradle file and full crash list?

Comment: Don't want to hijack OPs question by editing it, but this will result in the same problem: [gradle](http://pastebin.com/1zsrZMM8), [call causing exception](http://pastebin.com/h9jwcf9k), [exception](http://pastebin.com/fh19AtSd).

Comment: @DougStevenson Added requested information to the previous comment.

Comment: Have you tried building new, barebones test app to see how this works?  I just did that and I didn't have any problems in debug mode.

Comment: @DougStevenson Same result with a brand new app. Just to make sure, I'm talking about the `buildType` `debug` that is defined in the gradle file, not AndroidStudio debug mode.

Comment: @Baz Yes, that's what I am using. The build variant makes no difference for me in loading a raw resource into a webview like you're doing.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've uploaded my sample project [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/498403/app.zip). There must be something I'm doing that's different to what you're doing. Maybe you can have a look?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have any problems with the other files in the raw folder? And something else: do you have proguard enabled for any of the two variants (debug and release)? I'm trying to understand what's going on in build that's working that in debug it's not

Comment: @DDsix I posted my gradle file in a previous comment. Yes, release build uses proguard.

Comment: Well then try to enable proguard on debug, see if that works

Comment: @Ascorbin Have a look at [DDsix's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35647121/1449199). It worked for me.

Comment: @Baz I'm not working anymore on the project that I had this problem with, so I can't tell. It does make sense though ;)

Comment: @Ascorbin I see. Well, it's up to you if you want to accept the answer. I can confirm that it's working though.

Comment: @Baz I'll trust you with that ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try removing the suffix to your debug mode.

Also, please make sure in proguard rules you have

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {public static <fields>;}
-keep class **.R$*
```

EDIT: 
After figuring out the problem (the debug app package suffix ".debug"), try to load the file this way:

```
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_web_file;
    Uri myFileUri = Uri.parse(path);
    File file = new File(myFileUri.toString());
    webview.loadUrl(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

2nd EDIT:
If that still doesn't work (although for me it works), try this: load the file to the webview using an input stream.

```
String prompt = "";
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_web_file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(buffer);
    prompt = new String(buffer);
    inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

webview.loadData(prompt,"text/html","utf-8");
```

Comment: I'm afraid removing the suffix isn't an option for me. The proguard rules won't change anything as the debug buildType doesn't use proguard.

Comment: Remove it to see if that's the problem. If that's what causes it, you would have to load your resource in a different way.

Comment: First see if that's the problem, then we'll find a way to fix it

Comment: When I remove the suffix, it works just fine. So is there any option to use the suffix and still be able to load the html file? All other resources work just fine despite the suffix.

Comment: That looks very similar to Nick's answer. That one didn't work for me.

Comment: The thing is you get a wrong path to the file when suffix is added using the normal way (the one with android_res). Have you tried getting an input stream to the raw file and then loading that file on the webview using loadData() method?

Comment: I'll give that a go after lunch.

Comment: Alright, your first update loads a blank webview; no exception or error at all. Your second update does the trick. Good job!

Comment: Glad I could help you

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't accept your answer as this isn't my question. I'll try to get the OP to accept it though.

Comment: Thanks @DDsix those proguard rules to keep R really helped us solve a similar issue (same error). Where we have a webview loading css from res/raw that's in a library project. Progaud was optimizing the libraries R.class.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Try this one it works for me.

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/filename.html");
```

Comment: Works fine when using the release build type, but doesn't work when using the debug build type.

Answer (score 2):

As you may have realised, the raw directory was not intended for direct path access ([see docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)) and the assets directory is preferred.

From API level 8 you could try this slightly more verbose method, but I've had mixed success:

```
WebView webview = ...;
String path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.imprint);
webview.loadUrl(path);
```

Alternatively the res path should work with the 3 slashes and colon both present, if it isn't working for Debug, there could be a problem with how your debug version is compiled, you should show/check your gradle file

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/imprint.html");
```

Comment: I've tried it with `webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/eula_consumer.html")` and can confirm that it doesn't work. Please check the gradle setup in the comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the same thing by using **android_asset** folder, instead of raw folder.
Just put all your .html files in to asset.

Syntax is as below :

```
setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///**android_asset**/xyz.html");
```

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't support the default Android internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the reason behind it was a diferent `applicationId` of the debug flavor.
Based on DDsix's answer, this is what worked best for me.

It handles:

- Different `applicationId`s in different Build Variants
- Special characters in HTML (åäá)
- Localization of the HTML file in diferent raw folders (raw, raw-en, raw-xyz)

**Code**

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(rawFileResId);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log Exception
} finally {
    try {
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log Exception
    }
}
String html = stringBuilder.toString();
webView.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Use `loadDataWithBaseURL()` instead of `loadData()` if you are using CSS that is also in the raw folder

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/raw/", html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/filename.html");
```