# Accesing a resource from android library from the library code

Tags: android, split, android-webview

I have a project that loaded an html file to a WebView in a Custom view class, it worked ok when i compiled as an application.

```
loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/chart.html");
```

this code was part of a Custom view extending WebView. As a stand alone test app it worked ok after placing the Custom View in an activity.

I later changed the project to a library project.

After successfully adding this as a library project to another project, and getting everything to compile successfully, when running the main project using this custom control there is an error in the webview :

The webpage at **file:///android_res/raw/chart.html** could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I inspected the apk in Android Studio and the file chart.html is available  under res/raw/chart.html

loading of other html files in the same folder works normally when called from the main application code, only the webView line from the library module is not finding the resource.

I also tried in the Android Studio project copying the chart.html file from the library module to the main app resource folder, but it makes no difference it seems the resource files are merging at a single resource folder from the main app, but only the code in the main app can find the files, not so the code from the library, even though that particular file is from the library module.

in logcat i see:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "lu0.com.ar.yangSim.R$raw" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/base.apk", zip file
> "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip
> file "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip
> file
> "/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/lu0.com.ar.yangSim-1/lib/x86,
> /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

Answer (score 0):

Issue doesn't seem to be specific to library, possible to having different flavors configured, in original case moving the library code to main project didn't solve the problem, instead had issues similar to 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777566/file-under-res-raw-not-accessible-in-debug-buildvariant).

Finally solved in this case moving the resource files to assets folder and loading with

```
loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chart.html");
```