# exporting resources in a library with ADT 15.01

Tags: android, resources

There are other questions about this but I didn't find a clear answer.
With Android ADT 15.01 I need to create a lib that should just export resources: drawable, xml, etc.

Is it possible to export resources from a lib or not?

what is correct this https://stackoverflow.com/q/1831815/987753 or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/4895227/987753?

If it is possible how do you do it?
In the bin folder of my lib project I found a classes folder with the .class files and a res folder with the drawables. The jar file is almost empty: just 166 bytes.

Comment: Checking the google forum it looks like it should be possible so I do not understand why in my jar files the resources are not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it adding the res folder to the "java build paths"-"Source tab".
So one question is: why do I need to do so for a lib if I do not need to do it for a normal application?

Comment: Hey,
Can you please elaborate? I'm also trying to have an android library include its resources in its final jar but so far unable to.

I tried adding to that library's build path the resources directory but that did not seem to help. Is that what you meant? Or did you add it to the build path of the application referencing that library?

Comment: I have the same issue. can you please explain how you solved the issue