# Sharing jars for Android

Tags: android, jar, share

I've created a set of custom widgets for Android. What would be the easiest to share them with developers ? Using jar files ? How ?

Thanks

Comment: Make your widgets to libraries

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828448/android-is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-library-to-use-across-several-appilc  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085313/how-to-create-your-own-library-for-android-development-to-be-used-in-every-progr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for creating library >>

You have to create Android Library Project. Create android project in Eclipse,

enter Project Properties -> Android and check **isLibrary property.** Now you can add this library to you Application project by adding it to list on the same property page.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

for creating jar file>>

In Eclipse, you can use the "export" option on the project to create a jar file. This will open the JAR creation wizard.